# Why do several function calls only yield the last result?

Tags: javascript, function

This is my `bark` function using `return`. When I call it, I am calling it four times but I only get the value of the last function which is `bark("lady", 17);` and if I use this function with just `console.log` instead of `return`, then it will show me all four result.

Why is this happening and why can’t I see the result of all function calls?

```
function bark(name, weight) {
  var barkVoice;

  if (weight > 20) {
    barkVoice = name + " says WOOF WOOF";
  } else {
    barkVoice = name + " says woof woof";
  }

  return barkVoice;
}

bark("rover", 23);
bark("spot", 13);
bark("spike", 53);
bark("lady", 17);
```

Comment: Your functions are fine, if you want to "experiment" in the console directly, to see what happens, then either 1-  execute your `bark` functions separately in the console or 2 - wrap `console.log()` around the calls : `console.log(bark("rover", 23));`  or 3 - put all your results in an array, then print the result array

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your environment is probably a console. It usually takes the last expression and prints it.

If you run

```
console.log(bark("rover", 23));
console.log(bark("spot", 13));
console.log(bark("spike", 53));
console.log(bark("lady", 17));
```

It should behave as you want it to.

Comment: Other possibilities include `console.log(bark("rover", 23), bark("spot", 13), …);` and `[ [ "rover", 23 ], [ "spot", 13 ], … ].forEach((input) => console.log(bark(...input)));`.